# Identifying a Cauchy Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

I believe this is a Cauchy distribution, but I am having a hard time identifying the parameters. Could someone help me to identify the value of $\gamma$ and $x_0$ if this is indeed a Cauchy distribution?

$$f(x) = \frac{2}{\pi\sqrt{3}}\frac{1}{\left(1 + \dfrac{x^{2}}{\sqrt3}\right)^2}$$

Comment: It's not Cauchy, [it's something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution).

Comment: Sorry just updated the formula, do you think it is cauchy now?

Comment: There must be an error : it should be $(t/\sqrt{3})^2$ in the denominator, and, as J.G. said, it is not a Cauchy but a Student t-distribution with parameter $\gamma = 3$

Comment: I think @JeanMarie means $\nu=3$.

Comment: @J.G. You are right.